# Alternative for MySQL binary(16) in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I've got MySQL procedure which looks like

```
create procedure 'name' (in param_oid binary(16), out param2_oid binary(16)...
```

and when I am trying to execute it from c# code it return me exception (System.FormatException)

it's how I am executing it

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param_oid', myvariable);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@param2_oid', MySqlDbType.Binary);
cmd.Parameters['@param2_oid'].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In my opinion MySqlDbType.Binary isn't best idea to support binary(16). What's the alternative for it?

Comment: What is the data type of your variables?

Comment: I am sending Byte[] in myvariable

Comment: In c#, I'm pretty sure `'@param_oid'` won't compile.are you sure you provide the correct code?

Comment: Why are you specifying `MySqlDbType.Binary` as the *value* for your parameter? That's broken.

Comment: Well it's like Patrick Hofman answered - I just change AddWithValue to Add and it's working fine. 

Hmm '@param_oid' compile and work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter call is wrong. You call `AddWithValue` but instead of adding a variable as second parameter you supply the data type.

You should use `Add` instead.

Comment: @boski: Any luck? Need more help?